# drupal 7 + services 3 - inserting nodes with select fields

Tags: nodes, services, ajax, 8

I'm using Drupal 7 + Services 3 to create nodes with POST and JSON. Everything works fine, except field types of select - entity reference select or plain text.

The entity reference uses the autocomplete widget, while the text select is a plain radio button.

This is the format I'm using:

```
"field_urgency": {
    "und": [  {  "value": 1    }   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I figured this out:

```
    {
    "title": "some more tests",
    "type": "weed",
    "field_sprouts": {
        "und": [ 8,9 ]
    },
    "field_urgency": {
        "en": [
            {
                "value": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    "field_species": {
        "und": [ 4 ]
    }
 }
```

species and sprouts are entity references and only need the nid of the target (no value= or target_id= or anything).
For unknown reason (as of yet), the urgency field required a language to be defined (other then und[efined]). Its the only select field here with a normal select list, not entity refernce.
Make sure your widgets are **select list** and not auto complete.

Answer (score -1):

The PUT format for boolean or select list :

```
{
  "field_order_status":{
    "und":["1"]
  }
}
```

it would be ok.