# How do I PUT update on a node using services 3

Tags: javascript, users, services, 8

I have a node with field_order_status field(not required) in list(text) type and radio button widget and I want to update a node(nid:95) but my sample JSON PUT content(application/json) throws Status 406 Error:

```
{"form_errors":{"field_order_status][und":"An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."}}
```

my content is:

```
{
  "field_order_status":{
    "und":[
      {
        "value": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

sample url:

```
http://localhost/caesarschickencms/createorder/node/95
```

Services 3.4, Drupal 7.22

**Notes:** 
When I tried replacing und with other values like 'en', it accepts but not updates, refer to [drupal 7 + services 3 - inserting nodes with select fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/61124/drupal-7-services-3-inserting-nodes-with-select-fields/78976#78976)

And Devel page vars dump:
[image]

What would be missing?

Answer (score 2):

What Services version do you use?

Since Services 7.3.4 we deen to set **Cookie** & **X-CSRF Token** on header for every (PUT/POST) execution

Please check this comment too
https://drupal.org/comment/6491362#comment-6491362

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an issue with X-CSRF Token because the error send by server will be different.

But Drupal expect a value like "payment_to_valid", "order_shipping", "checkout_login" or "Pending".