# Drupal Rest Service - Create node problem

Tags: 8

I'm using POSTER add-on (Firefox) to create a node.(REST service). I couldn't able to create node having select/checkbox item. Getting following error in response.

["An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator"]

How to resolve this? I'm able to create node if post data doesn't contains select/checkbox data. My problem is exactly related to the following link. But I couldn't find solution.

[drupal 7 + services 3 - inserting nodes with select fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/61124/drupal-7-services-3-inserting-nodes-with-select-fields)

If I replace 'und' to 'en' in json format, the node is being created but with null values.

I've found following messages under Recent log messages.

Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain()
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in list_field_validate() 
Illegal choice in LABEL element.

Here 'LABEL' is the label(name) of the filed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.. finally I got solution for my problem. Here is the solution.

In JSON format, Here is the correct way to handle LIST type fields

"field_select_options":{"und":["4"]}

(Initially I tried "field_select_options":{"und":[{"value":"4"}]} which results error in response.)

Thanks, I got the solution from https://drupal.org/node/1971484